How to pass a long by value?
I'm trying to understand how to (or if it is possible to) pass a long to a C function by value. Here's my simple test C function:
#include <stdio.h>
long addone (long x) {
        printf("c got %li\n", x);
        fflush(stdout);
        return 1+x;
}

And here's my cobol code:
identification division.
program-id. ccalltest.
data division.
working-storage section.
01      my-val  usage binary-long.
01      my-rc   usage binary-long.
procedure division.
move 10 to my-val.
call 'addone' using 
        by content my-val
        giving my-rc.
display my-val.
display my-rc.
stop run.

I compile with
cobc -x -free cobolcode.cob ccode.c -lc

What actually happens, though, is C receives and prints a suspiciously large number (which may actually be a pointer, I'm not sure), instead of the value that I expect, 10. Am I doing something wrong here or is this use case not supported?
Here's an example of the program output (the non-10 numbers change from run to run):
c got 140725928122192
+0000000010
+1324668753

I'm using GnuCOBOL 3.1.2.0 and GCC 14.2.1.

I have 0 experience with cobol, but are you sure that "by content my-val" isn't actually getting the value stored at memory address 10, rather than passing 10?  Should it be "by value my-val"?

It should indeed be "by value". "By content" passes a pointer to a temporary copy of the variable.

Solution: by value
As pointed out by the commenters, the solution is to use by value, not by content. This is actually explained in the GnuCOBOL programmer's guide, section 7.8.5 (the CALL statement). The programmer's guide can be found at this link: https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/guides.html

Apart from considering changing that to a "community answer" (edit, then mark "community wiki") please mark this answer as "solution", so that this question is "visibly solved" - thank you.

Something to possibly add to the community answer as well: If you want to pass a C long then you likely want to use the standard USAGE BINARY-DOUBLE, possibly conditional, because the C storage is often bigger than the minimal COBOL range which is used in GnuCOBOL. If you only use this compiler you can use the extension BINARY-C-LONG which matches C to whatever environment you use.
